# Create object from array without database table?

Tags: php, laravel, object

I can't seem to find an answer simple enough or similar enough. Maybe it's my search terms?

I want to create an array for a form and assign an id to each entry. That way I don't have to call to the db or store a string that might change in the future. The array/object would only have 3-4 values.

For example:

id: 1
name: 'cancel order'

id: 2
name: 'place hold;

The contents would be used in a foreach loop in a laravel blade.

Am I heading in the right direction, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
  $array = [
        "1" => "cancel order",
        "2" => "place hold",
        "3" => "any text"
    ];
```

Please see:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Comment: How do I reference the id?

Comment: Sorry, hit return too soon.
@foreach($changeOrderStatus as $changeStatus)

                                                <option
                                                    value="{{$changeStatus->name}}"
                                                    {{ $changeStatus->name == old('changeStatus') ? 'selected' : ''}}>
                                                    {{ $changeStatus->name }}
                                                </option>

                                            @endforeach

How do I format this? Argh!

Comment: For reference, with the posted code, it would be `@foreach($array as $id => $name)<option value="{{ $id }} {{ old('changeStatus') == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $name }}</option>` Difference between an array of nested arrays (or objects) and a single associative array.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured that last part out.

Between your answer and mine, I'm good. Thanks!

```
            <option
               value="{{$changeStatus['id']}}"
                      {{ $changeStatus['name'] == old('changeStatus') ? 'selected' : ''}}>
                      {{ $changeStatus['name'] }}
                       </option>
```

Comment: You'd want this line to use `['id']`, not `['name']`: `{{ $changeStatus['id'] == old('changeStatus') ? 'selected' : ''}}`; the `value=...` will be in `old()`, not the name.